# No open in new tab on right click menu on complex links in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

This is a weird bug that we've been able to repeat across several installations of IE8. For some reason when you have a link in a web page that contains code (valid as an html5 document - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) IE8 appears to treat it as an image instead of a link.

Normally you right click on a link and it has an option to open the link in a new tab. But when you throw this link at it:

```
<a href="/mylink.html">
   <div class="boxed">
      <div class="colourbar">
          <div style="height: 14px;" class="type">
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Release type: </span>
            Joint Media Release
          </div>
          <h3 style="height: auto; overflow: visible;" class="title">More support for echidnas</h3>
          <div style="height: 16px;" class="imagined">
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Released by: </span>
            Roger B Arth
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

**How can I convince IE8 that this is a link and to treat it like a link for right click purposes?** It treats it as a link just fine if you ctrl-click on it or even just a plain old normal click...